# Hide element onClick React based on Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of 3 filters that will show based on their id, when clicked it will show the filters matching the id but I would like to hide it if clicked again. So if Filter 1 is clicked it should show and then if clicked again it should hide

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpFE0uZN94N_RY2lavn

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'

 export default class Catalogue extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      filterListShow: false,
      active: false
    }
    this.handleShowFilterList = this.handleShowFilterList.bind(this)
  }

  // Show Filter checklist onClick
  handleShowFilterList(id) {
    this.setState({
      filterListShow: id,
      active: false    })
  }


  render() {

    const { filterListShow } = this.state

    let test = ''
    if (filterListShow === 1) {
      test = (<div>show 1</div>)
    }
    else if (filterListShow === 2) {
      test = (<div>show 2{console.log(2)}</div>)
    }
    else if (filterListShow === 3) {
      test = (<div>show 3{console.log(3)}</div>)
    }

    return (
      <div >
        <div onClick={()=> this.handleShowFilterList(1)}>
        Show Filter 1 
        </div>
        <div onClick={()=> this.handleShowFilterList(2)}>
        Show Filter 2
        </div>
        <div onClick={()=> this.handleShowFilterList(3)}>
        Show Filter 3
        </div>
        {test}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: And you're question is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another check in the `onClick` handler to check whether the current state is the same as the id of the element clicked,

```
// Show Filter checklist onClick
  handleShowFilterList(id) {
    if(this.state.filterListShow !== id) {
      this.setState({
        filterListShow: id,
        active: false    })
    } else {
       this.setState({filterListShow: false})
    }
  }
```

**[DEMO](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpFGMXe-sC8HzW6I6ij)**

Comment: Glad to be of help buddy :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the condition in `handleShowFilterList` function, if same item has been clicked again then reset the state value of `filterListShow` variable.

Like this:

```
handleShowFilterList(id) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        //if same then reset otherwise assign new id
        filterListShow: prevState.filterListShow == id ? false : id,    
        active: false  
    }))
}
```

[**Working Code.**](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpFFvkqF1hfSHDd7xy5)

Comment: this works for filter 1 but for the others it doesn't hide them

Comment: @tomharrison sorry, it was a typo, check the code again, it is working :)